# Search a specific cell from a range in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a little problem concerning comparing different cells together, that's I need to compare each cell in column A, versus the whole column B and get the specified found cell in the adjacent column c cell.

I used this equation:

`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A61,B:B, 0)), "No Match", "Match on Row " & MATCH(A61,B:B, 0))`

and this is the result:

```
18       001220     No Match
19       001221     No Match
20       001222     No Match
21       001223     No Match
22       001224     No Match
101264   00040      Match on Row 121
```

Note that all data types are stored as text. and this is mandatory.

The problem is that this formula skips some data and doesn't collect them from column b except when being changed from text to general or number, which will damage my worksheet, as many cells start with zeros.

Comment: Does the data in column B follow a specific format that you can describe in excel?

Comment: All formats are text, although majority of cells contain numbers, this is because many cells start with 0, 00, or 000.

Comment: That was not what I meant exactly. Let me try rephrase: is the format of all numbers ######, meaning there is always 6 digits? In excel for instance, users can use `=text(A1,"00000#")` to convert let's say `1000` to `001000`.

Comment: No, numbers are variable in digits, sometimes 2 or 6 or 7 or 9 digits.

Comment: It might be slow, but you can try this match in place of your first one: `MATCH(A61*1,B:B*1, 0)` and after making the change, press Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of Enter to make the formula work.

Comment: Well, it didn't work perfectly, e.g. cell A1 has the value of 20, the formula led me to row 50 that contains the value of 00020 in cell B2,

Comment: Isn't this what your current formula was skipping? If not, then please make your problem clearer.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, but I need an exact match between two values, that's the purpose of all my work.

Comment: The old formula provided me partially with this, but skipped some items. now the new formula avoided this, but misled me by providing me with non exact results.

Comment: Please if you could help me to find a match between exact values (column A & B), noting that all values are stored as text.

Comment: I can't understand your problem. Please put examples on [this google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10tgAwvDZ_em7GtZC_nascikqyy37rm3RE8yqE2j8ohI/edit?usp=sharing) with your current formula, and the expected result. Include working values and those that are not working. Around 10 different values covering as many different scenarios as possible would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your *lookup_value* can be either text or a number but you are *always* looking for it as text, then format the *lookup_value* with a format mask that covers both scenarios. It seems that *most* of your sample data is six digits with leading zeroes if necessary so `TEXT(A61, "000000;@")` should work to leave text values alone and format numbers to text with a minimum of six digits with leading zeroes if necessary.The zeroes in front of the semi-colon format numbers as text; the @ behind the semi-colon leaves text alone.
2. Excel 2007 can drastically shorten that formula with `IFERROR` by removing the redundancy.

For your sample formula that would make,

`=IFERROR("Match on Row " & MATCH(TEXT(A61, "000000;@"), B:B, 0), "No Match")`